# Calculate Sum of Products Over Time With Changes in Historical Values

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Given two (simplified) tables in Access 2010:

```
**tblDailyLabour**
DailyLabourID - PK
DateRecorded
EmployeeID
QtyHours

**tblEmployeeHistory**
EmpHistoryID - PK
DateApplicable
EmployeeID
PayRate
```

Employee1 is entered into the database today. He's set in an 'Address Book' of employees with various values assigned to him. As of today he has a PayRate of $23.50/hr.

So from today moving forward, all hours logged will be calculated against today's rate for Employee1 at (23.50 * [QtyHours])
A month goes by and Employee1 gets a wage increase to $25.00/hr. This value is logged as a new entry in the 'Employee History' and is active as of, say, April 17th. So from April 17th onward he is now being calculated at (25.00 * [QtyHours]).

On a daily report this is straight forward as a query checks the report date and calculates the totals for Employee1. Whether the report is March 17th or April 25th, the query looks up the assigned rate and figures the total cost.

However, if I were to create an administrative report that was to evaluate the total cost of all days between March 17th and June 3rd, there may be several changes in the employee rates that need to be accounted for.

This is where I'm having a problem. I can't figure out how to not show any previous rates if DateApplicable is <= DateRecorded.

How might I go about writing a query that determines the rate on each day - dependent on the value in the Employee History - and calculate a total sum?

I apologize in advance if this question isn't phrased very well, but thanks a heap for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it might be easier if you did a date range (start date & end date) in the 'address book' instead of just the start date.
On the current record, make the end date 12/31/9999. When entering a new current record, update the end date of the last record.

Comment: Thank you Tom. That's actually a nice, straight forward solution and seems to be working just fine. The user shouldn't even have to see the field if I automatically update it when a new record is added to the Employee History. Cheers!